# Can UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer be added on a subview that is not near screen edge?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I downloaded this example from github: https://github.com/PaulSolt/UIScreenEdgePanGestureDemo
It seems to work fine. However, if I change the greenview left frame to be say 30 points from superview in storyboard (not the same with superview as in example), and change this code

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftEdgeGesture];
```

to

```
[_edgeView addGestureRecognizer:leftEdgeGesture];
```

the gesture does not respond.
I guess you can not add a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to a subview unless the subview edge is near the screen edge, but I need to know if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.. It only works for views that touches edge.